# Change user state in database based on session

Tags: python, flask, flask-session

I have webapp that shows who is currently logged in on it's front page. I did that by having isActive field in user model, if user is logged isActive = True if user is logged out isActive = False. Unfortunately now I needed to implement auto log out on browser close and I've achieved that thanks to

```py
REMEMBER_COOKIE_DURATION = datetime.timedelta(minutes=0)
app.config["SESSION_PERMANENT"] = False
```

But this obviously doesn't change state in database

My approach was to check active users and check sessions, get the ID's of both and compare them. If user ID is in active_user_list and not in session_id get this user ID and change it's state in database.

```
def checking_loop():
    delay = 180
    while True:
        active_users = User.query.filter_by(isActive=True).all()
        #don't worry about querying database in a loop It's stored locally 
        #on the PC
        active_users_id = []
        user_in_session = []
    
        if session.get('_user_id'):
            user_in_session.append(session['_user_id'])

        for x in active_users:
            active_users_id.append(x.id)
        
        users_to_logout = [x for x in active_users_id if x not in user_in_session]

        time.sleep(delay)

        
logout_loop = Thread(target=checking_loop)
logout_loop.start()
```

So, what's not working? I didn't know that when I call session I only get one ID.
Can I make this work somehow or do you have a better approach for this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this will work. Flask session depends on context https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/reqcontext/#how-the-context-works. I don't know how your code works without view context, but generally global session derives it's value from currently served request (the assumption is only one request can be handled at the time). So in session you'll get current user, not all users.

I'm not sure when session connected to user is deleted or how to iterate over active sessions, but if they are stored in cookies backend won't be able to do that.